# Passing params to Shiny server context in quarto

Tags: r, shiny, quarto

I expected `params` to be available in code chunks with `#| context: server`, but that is not the case:

````
---
title: "test"
format: html
editor: visual
server: shiny
params:
  n: 5
---

```{r}
verbatimTextOutput("text")
```

```{r}
#| context: server

output$text <- shiny::renderText(params$n)
```
````

[image]

I can do this instead:

````
---
title: "test"
format: html
editor: visual
server: shiny
params:
  n: 5
---

```{r}
verbatimTextOutput("text")
```

```{r}
#| context: data
#| include: false

n <- params$n
```

```{r}
#| context: server

output$text <- shiny::renderText(n)
```
````

but then I have to manage each `param` element individually.

This also works:

````
---
title: "test"
format: html
editor: visual
server: shiny
params:
  n: 5
---

```{r}
verbatimTextOutput("text")
```

```{r}
#| context: data
#| include: false

params2 <- params
```

```{r}
#| context: server

output$text <- shiny::renderText(params2$n)
```
````

this approach strikes me as slightly better because I can reference all parameters in the same way throughout the report and I don't have to manage each param individually.

But the question remains: why can't I use `params$n` in `#| context: server`? There is no discussion of `params` in a shiny context [here](https://quarto.org/docs/computations/parameters.html#knitr).

Comment: Looks like a bug. I'd file an issue [here](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-r/issues).

Comment: Issue filed [here](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-r/issues/78)